# regular expression for words beginning with a certain string (javascript)

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to write a regular expression in javascript for finding if any words in a sentence start with a particular phrase. Eg, I'd like to know if "by" is contained at the beginning of any word in the following sentence :
"The Tipping Point by Malcolm Gladwell".

I tried using  `\b` but `/\bsor/` will match a sentence like 'Mary's organ is broken.' ie it treats punctuation as a word boundary and starts matching after them.
Any thoughts?

Comment: `/\bsor/.test("Mary's organ is broken.")` returns *false*.

Comment: ah right, I meant to say that that regex matches s*space*or

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**/(?:\s|^)bar/** *-- perhaps -- although see the answer for splitting it first*

```
/(?:\s|^)bar/.test("bar")     // true
/(?:\s|^)bar/.test("foo bar") // true
/(?:\s|^)bar/.test("foo'bar") // false
/(?:\s|^)bar/.test("Sentence One.bar Two.") // false ... "oops"?
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using [split](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) on the sentence to try your expression on every word?

You could also use [indexOf](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_IndexOf.asp) rather than a regexp.

Answer (score 0):

On Regexpedia, there is an article has the code and explainations.

[JavaScript Search for Lines Beginning with a Word](http://www.regexpedia.com/JavaScript_Search_for_Lines_Beginning_with_a_Word)